# convergence for a series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

Show that the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{[\frac{(1+\epsilon)\log n}{\log\log n}]!}$$converges for $\epsilon>0$.
Stirling's approximation gives that the convergence for the series is equivalent to the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi [\frac{(1+\epsilon)\log n}{\log\log n}]}}\left(\frac{e}{[\frac{(1+\epsilon)\log n}{\log\log n}]}\right)^{[\frac{(1+\epsilon)\log n}{\log\log n} ]}.$$
But it is still hard to see the convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a research level question, but I feel like answering it. Simply, use the elementary estimate
$$\log(m!)\sim m\log m.$$
The symbol $\sim$ means that the ratio of the two sides tends to $1$. For
$$m=\left[\frac{(1+\epsilon)\log n}{\log\log n}\right],$$
this becomes
$$\log(m!)\sim\frac{(1+\epsilon)\log n}{\log\log n}\log m\sim(1+\epsilon)\log n.$$
In particular, if $n$ is sufficiently large in terms of $\epsilon,$
then
$$m!>n^{1+\epsilon/2}.$$
Convergence is immediate from here.

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that they often are raised at the same time at math.stackexchange, as it is the case here too. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710437. Answering such non-research questions (often in the imperative form "Show that ..." like here) encourages this misuse of MO.

Comment: @PeterMueller I agree, and sometimes I notice this before giving an answer.